# Is it possible to add a keyup listener to a form tag to trigger the submit event even if there is no submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

Consider a HTML-form, which includes several input fields and an icon from the material-icons library. I have added a click-listener to the icon, such that the form is submitted when clicking on the icon.

Now I want to go ahead and also add a keyup-Listener, such that the form will be submitted whenever I hit the 'Enter'-key. I was trying to just add this listener to the form-element. This doesn't work, however.

I am afraid that I might have to add this event-listener to each of my input fields and am curious on as there is another way of achieving what I want? Note, though, that I don't have a submit-button, I only have the icon.

Comment: What's wrong with the [onsubmit](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp) event? Then simply put a `<button type="submit">` on the form

Comment: I actually just found out that it works with adding an event-listener to the form-tag. The mistake that I made was that I used 'keyUp' instead of 'keyup'. That was a bit stupid. I'll go ahead and close the question. Sorry about that!